styling right click menu vscode
i am styling my vscode to my liking. so far it is alright but i can't figure out how to style the right click menu. it is linked to the menu bar. had to remove the menu bar menu's background cause it interfered with the background i had set to it.
but that made the right click menu for the editor transparent.
the code i have:
.shadow-root-host
> .context-view.monaco-component.monaco-menu-container.bottom.left.fixed
> .monaco-scrollable-element
> .monaco-menu
> .monaco-action-bar.vertical {
box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) !important;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
background-image: linear-gradient(#30363d 0%, #010409 100%) !important;
backdrop-filter: blur(3px) !important;
border-radius: 20px !important;
border: 1px solid #303031 !important;}

somehow when inspecting vscode and breaking on subtree mod it shows me this element. but for some reason it doesn't work
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {    
"menu.background": "#00000000"
},

this is the styling in the json file. but that interferes with the styling set to the main menu bar drop down list
